# Private-key encryption scheme with indistinguishable encryptions in presence of eavesdropper.

Tags: polynomials, cryptography

I want to prove the following statement:
There is a private-key encryption scheme that has indistinguishable encryptions in the presence of an eavesdropper, but not indistinguishable multiple encryptions in the presence of an eavesdropper.

I must say, I am struggling quite a bit studying cryptography. I mostly really want to UNDERSTAND how to start and approach this question. I have all the definitions at hand, but I just have no clue on how to start proving this.

***Definition*** indistinguishable encryptions in the presence of an eavesdropper:

$Pr[PrivK^{eav}_{A, \Pi}(n) = 1] = \frac{1}{2} + negl(n)$

***Definition*** indistinguishable multiple encryptions in the presence of an eavesdropper:

$Pr[PrivK^{mult}_{A, \Pi}(n) = 1] \leq \frac{1}{2} + negl(n)$

Where $PrivK^{eav}_{A, \Pi}$ is the Adversarial Indistinguishability Experiment.

I was thinking, as a first approach, of a proof by contradiction, assuming it is smaller than $\frac{1}{2} + negl(n)$. BUT, can I even do that? Is $K^{mult}_{A, \Pi}(n)$ the same as $K^{eav}_{A, \Pi}(n)$? It feels wrong to assume that.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do "indistinguishable encryptions" and "indistinguishable multiple encryptions" mean?

Comment: @Arthur see new edit

Comment: What exactly are the experiments $PrivK^{eav}_{A, \Pi}(n)$ and $PrivK^{mult}_{A, \Pi}(n)$? It's probably the event that an attacker guesses correctly (and that probably should be approximately equal to 0.5) between a random message and an encrypted message or between the possible originators of a message or something similar. But the definition of the experiments contains what the capabilities of the attacker exactly are, and that is of course crucial here, because that's what make the difference between eav and mult.